# Real numbers subscript + and bar overhead

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

Please refer to Lawrence Evans Book on PDE (2nd edition) page 70.  http://www.mif.vu.lt/~algirdas/Evans.pdf (page 80 here) on the Euler-Poisson-Darboux equation. What does the notation $\bar{\mathbb{R}}_{+}$ mean? And why is $U\in C^{m}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}_{+}\times[0,\infty))$? How does that come from the fact that $u\in C^{m}(\mathbb{R}^{n}\times[0,\infty))$?

Comment: The notation question is the extended positive reals (i.e. $[0,+\infty]$)

Answer (score 3):

$$\mathbb{R}_+=[0,+\infty)\qquad\bar{\mathbb{R}}_{+}=\mathbb R_+\cup\{+\infty\}$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain to me why $U\in C^{m}(\bar{\mathbb{R}}_{+}\times[0,\infty))$ ?

Comment: Sorry but no, unless you express in your own terms the statement and the problem you have with it.